# python3 code second attempt at score counter got all syntax down, now saying new_score is undefined in a parameter

Tags: python, parameters, undefined

I checked and double checked from the last time I posted. I believe I have my logic correct now, and I think I have a decent start, I am testing the code I have now just to see if it will run, but I am getting one of my parameters when I call the function as being undefined in line 15.

I do not see a question that I can actually use the answers to help me.

I am open to all forms of critique, this is my second attempt now to create a score counter that does not go past 200. 
The code is as follows

```
    score = 0
    def total_score(score):

     """function that loops by adding numbers to a list and totaling thesum 
      each time a new number is inputed by a user till if adds up to 200"""
        while score >= 0 and score <= 200:
            new_score= score 
            score = int(input())
            print("what is the score? " + score)


            print(new_score)
        if new_score >= 200: 
            print("busted! revert back to previous score")
            print(new_score)
    total_score(score)
```

edited to try a mentioned alternative, its no longer saying undefined but it is not printing anything at all or asking for input.

Comment: This is the error I am getting now.                                                                                                               File "C:/Users/Lindsey/Documents/testscore.py", line 15, in <module>
    total_score(score, new_score)
NameError: name 'new_score' is not defined
>>>

Comment: did you initialize new_score,

Comment: Also I have not added a list yet as I was just testing the code I have now to see if it would even run to ask for input. After I can make it do that I am going to add a list, if I understand it right when I use the list

Comment: hmmm, I do not think I did, I think I didn't know I had to, to be honest.

Comment: function total_score requires two required params, new_scrore is undefined when you call that function

Comment: in line 10 I thought I did, is new_score = score + new_score, the wrong way to do it, would it be better if I did new_score = score +input() or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugged code:

```
def total_score(score): # get original score
    all_scores = [] # make a empty list for scores

    # set the total score to the original score
    new_score = score

    # create an infinite loop...
    while True:
        # add score to list
        all_scores.append(int(input("Enter a score: ")))

        # sum up the new score 
        # new score = original score + sum of all scores in list
        new_score = score + sum(all_scores)

        # if you are busted...
        if new_score >= 200:
            # print stuff
            print("busted! revert back to previous score")
            print(new_score) # print final score

            # break out of infinite loop
            break
```

Comment: Hmm I didn't think of that, I will try it. I just need to see if it runs just this simple. Will I be able to call that variable in the other loops of the function? that's why I had it in the arguments which I thought were called parameters. bahhhh

Comment: I did as you mentioned, its not giving the error but it is not printing nothing, I edited the code above to show what I did

Comment: thank you for explaining it clearly, I am glad to see I didn't just straight bomb the code and that it can be fixed as you have shown now time for me to really read and understand the differences in both our codes to see what I need to practice on more

Answer (score 0):

the error is in the last line when your calling the function

```
total_score(score, new_score)
```

here you have not defined what new_score value is so you are getting error
initialize new_score then pass the way you did for score

Comment: Alright thanks, I think I have to redo line 10 then.